# Extract data from a table of content with regex

Tags: regex

Consider the following String, which is a table of content

```
Table of Content

Name abc  ......... 20
Name fghkjkj kjkj . 31
Name.with.dot ..... 45
```

I want to extract the section's name '`Name abc`' '`Name fghkjkj kjkj`' and '`Name.with.dot`'

I didn't found yet the right regex to achieve that goal, any insights?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```
^.*?(?= \.+ \d+$)
```

assuming you're working line by line or have `MULTILINE` mode enabled. The [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) makes sure that we end the match as soon as only dots and a number follow on the line.

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Start of line
.*?    # Match any number of characters, as few as possible
(?=    # Look ahead to assert that the following matches from here:
 [ ]   # a space
 \.+   # one or more dots
 [ ]   # a space
 \d+   # a number
 $     # End of line
)      # End of lookahead
```

Comment: +1 for the solution and explanation. but I didn't get why do we need `MULTILINE`? or I missed something..

Comment: @Kent: If you're working on a multiline string, and don't split it into single lines before applying the regex, then we need to make sure that the anchors match on start/end of each line.

Answer (score 4):

This positive lookahead based regex should work:

```
^.+?(?= +\.+ +\d+$)
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/B5EdXF3SIz

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick:

```
^Name[ .]\w+(?:[. ]\w+)?
```

Explanation:

```
^     # Start of string
Name  # Literal string 'Name'
[ .]  # Space or period
\w+   # One or more word characters
(?:   # Start non-capturing group
[ .]  # Space or period
\w+   # One or more word characters
)     # Close noo-capturing group
?     # Make previous group optional
```

Live demo [**here**](http://rubular.com/r/rGQYRAyMXT).

Comment: Nice and short regex, but would have small problem with line `Name fghkjkj kjkj`

Comment: @Kent not sure how I missed that `:|` fixed!